# How to toggle radio button in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Html file

```
 <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor='let p of products;'>
  <div class="panel panel-light-grey border-grey">
    <div class="panel-heading border-grey">
      <div class="radio clip-radio radio-primary radio-lg ">
        <input type="radio" id="{{p.id}}" ngControl="selectedProduct" (ngModelChange)="selectProduct($event, p)" [(ngModel)]="p.selected"
          formControlName="selectedProduct" value={{p.id}}>
        <label for="{{p.id}}">
          <span class="panel-title text-azure text-extra-large" tooltip="{{p.product.title}}" placement="bottom">{{(p.product.title.length>24)? (p.product.title | titlecase | slice:0:24)+'..':(p.product.title | titlecase) }}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript file

```
  selectProduct(selected, item) {
    if (selected) {
      console.log(selected);
      this.request.title = item.product.title;
      this.request.product = item.product;
      this.request.currentQty = item.currentQty;
    }
  }

  changed(text: string) {
    if (!this.cRequestFirstWizard.invalid) {
      this.modelChanged.next(text);
    }
  }
```

I have a radio button in my form, which i want check and uncheck if clicked twice on that button, I mean i want to make a radio button toggle.

what are the changes i have to make in my typescript or html file so that, the functionality can work.

Comment: Why not go for a simple check box in that case?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview check this angular material toggle button, it might be of help

Comment: as suggested by @dou2abou you should go for a checkbox... easy and hassle free.

Comment: checkbox helps, but how to restrict it to select only one checkbox, just like a radio button.

Comment: @AsifAhmed what's your use-case? If you try to explain what it is exactly that you're trying to do, maybe the community could better help you.

Comment: i was looking to make radio button toggle, just the way checkbox toggles, but problem with check box is, i am not able to restrict user from checking multiple check boxes. http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/VGPhD/2/  just like this if i make use of radio button